# How to organize a CDK project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In a CDK application, you have a file to describe your stack class. And you have more than one developer working and modifying the same file to define their resources. This single file can be a point of contention while using Git. what are the ways I can organize my CDK project?

So far, I have used the directory structure that CDK CLI creates. And managing git merge conflicts manually. I expect to organize the project in such a way so that I can avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the [Recommended AWS CDK project structure for Python applications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/recommended-aws-cdk-project-structure-for-python-applications/) blog post. The [component sandbox stack](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-project-structure-python/blob/9b2c8f07796bdea3d31534a07643ade7f388461e/app.py#L27) there assumes the approach of a sandbox account per developer. You can make it work for several developers in a single sandbox account by adding a username of the currently logged-in user to the stack name (e.g. `UserManagementBackendSandboxApulver`).

This way, each developer can iterate on the stack code, and deploy to sandbox environment directly from their machine (using `cdk deploy`) without having a conflict with other developers. Once the developer is happy with the changes, the next step is to integrate with the rest of the team per the defined development worklfow, including conflict resolution.